# How to convert a generic type to a concrete type in Java

Tags: java, generics

Hi I  am currently working on some legacy code that I have inherited and I need to convert one type to another type to end my refactoring.
The problem I am having is that I have a object that returns a `Class<AbstractSuperClass>` but I need to convert it into a `AbstractSuperClass //(concrete object although abstract)`

What I tried to do was to use enum constant to represent concrete subclasses of an abstract class and then use the constants to instantiate objects. But all my attempts of casting have thus far failed.

If somebody could provide some pointers in the right direction for this situation it would be most helpful.

Comment: A `Class` object is not an `AbstractSuperClass` object. Casting will never work. Please clarify what it is you're doing or trying to do.

Comment: Hi thank you for a quick answer, what I try to do is returning a Class<AbstractSuperClass> via an enum (ENUMVAL(baseClassFoo).class) if I can succeed in converting this return type to the abstract class I have in my other method I can eliminate a lot of redundant code and use the algorithm defined in baseClassFoo without having to check with conditionals using dynamic dispatch instead.

Comment: Are you asking how to instantiate a class given its `Class` object? (Through reflection?)

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm hoping the abstract is just for the generic bound and they are actually providing concrete classes for the enum arguments (or whatever that is).

Comment: Yes I think that is what I am looking for , if that makes it possible to achieved what I described in my question above, e.g returning the enum value of type Class<AbstractSuperClass> and then instantiate a AbstractSuperClass class given this.  (Basically I return enum values of type  Class<baseClassFoo> types but I hope to use theese enum values to instantiate the AbstractSuperClass in the other class so that I can employ dynamic dispatch there ) @Sotirios yes that is the case : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear. It looks like you are trying to use enum constants to represent concrete subclasses of an abstract class, and you want to be able to use these constants to instantiate objects. This is possible:

```
public enum ConcreteClass {

    CONCRETE1(Concrete1.class),
    CONCRETE2(Concrete2.class);

    private final Class<? extends AbstractClass> clazz;

    private ConcreteClass(Class<? extends AbstractClass> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public AbstractClass instantiate() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return clazz.newInstance();
    }
}
```

With this you can do `AbstractClass obj = ConcreteClass.CONCRETE2.instantiate();`. You will have to do it in a `try` block as those exceptions are checked exceptions.

Personally I don't like using reflection for this. I think using a `Supplier<AbstractClass>` is nicer (requires Java 8):

```
public enum ConcreteClass {

    CONCRETE1(Concrete1::new),
    CONCRETE2(Concrete2::new);

    private final Supplier<AbstractClass> supplier;

    private ConcreteClass(Supplier<AbstractClass> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public AbstractClass instantiate(){
        return supplier.get();
    }
}
```

This approach doesn't use reflection, doesn't involve checked exceptions, and is more general as it can be used with classes that only have static factory methods and no public constructors.

Comment: no wildcard in the 2nd solution? :) but I agree, wildcard is hell.

Comment: @bayou.io I don't think the wildcard buys you anything in the second solution, whereas in the first example you need them to make it compile. I'm one of those strange people who actually likes wildcards.

Comment: hmm... yes, all call sites of an enum constructor are known, therefore it's less of a problem without wildcard. I'd [argue](http://bayou.io/draft/Wildcard_Case_Studies.html#Missing_Wildcards) that the real reason why wildcards could often be omitted is that the arguments are often lambda expression or method references, java type inference can take care of fitting the type.

Comment: @JKT No worries. Glad I could help.